# Why don't my images show up?

Tags: xetex, graphics, pdf, lyx

I am using LyX to create my documents. I then export them to plain LaTeX and use XeLaTeX to create a PDF output. My images show up in the LyX document but not in the PDF output.

LyX generates this code to insert an image:

```
\includegraphics{\string"some file\string".png}
```

I get errors like these:

```
[1] <"some file".eps>
Overfull \hbox (209.98003pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 58--62
```

and

```
** WARNING ** No filename specified for PSfile special.
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command PSfile (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="3" position="(158.675, 489.198)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "PSfile=""some file".eps" llx=-0 lly=-0 urx=528 ury..."
** WARNING ** >> Reading special command stopped around >>""some file".eps" llx=-0 lly=-0 urx=528 ury=178 rw...<<
```

Comment: Try this also : `\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{\string"some file\string".png}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use spaces in the file name. xetex has to call in the background ghostscript to convert the eps file and obviously the quotes needed to hide the spaces leads to problems in this step. `""some file".eps"` is simply not a sane file name.

Answer (score 1):

Your path format seems to be wrong  :-)

Comment: What should it be?

Comment: Please make a trial. Remove any spaces in directory or file name. And use `\includgraphics{yourfolder/yourfilename.eps}` or `\includgraphics{yourfolder/yourfilename.png}` (depends on your file format). I am assuming you know your tex compiler can handle your picture file format.

Comment: It works now that I've removed spaces from the file names and updated these in the tex file.